# onClick show/hide Want to collapse image size on hide javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I've just put this script together, but theres a problem with it, if the image is sat between text, it keeps the height difference when it's not visible, anyone got any ideas on how to collapse the size or something simlar when show/hiding?

Body

```
    a onclick="showImage();"> Click here</a>
    img id="loadingImage" src="image.png" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Script

```
function showImage(){
    var toggleImage = document.getElementById("loadingImage");
      if(toggleImage.style.visibility == "visible") {
         document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='hidden';
     }else{
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
}
}
```

Comment: use `display: none` / `display: inline`

Comment: @Switchfire : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone  refer this link for better understanding

Comment: Cheers that was helpful Pbk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `visibility`. Use `display` property instead.

As you can see @ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility):

> The (*visibility*) **hidden** value hides an element but leaves space where it would have been.